# Wordpress: Using pre_get_posts returns no results

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I'm using `pre_get_posts` to modify main wpquery to get variable products as single products. This is because plugin filters only work with main wpquery.

Is there any known reason why I would get 'no products found' when using `pre_get_posts` for the command `$product->set('post_type', 'product_variation')` ?

My function looks like:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rc_modify_query_get_design_projects' );
function rc_modify_query_get_design_projects( $product ) {
  global $wp_query;
  $product->set('post_type', 'product_variation');
}
```

Comment: Can you share the entire function?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my question, sorry for not doing it right away

Comment: This seems like a really heavy-handed `pre_get_posts` This will affect every single query that is made. You need to add some conditionals to check if the query being passed even matches what you are trying to filter.

Comment: Did the answer to your other question help you with this?